# How to pass a parameter to a downloaded script

Tags: linux, bash, github

I'm stuck passing a parameter(URL to download) to a script.

My goal is to create a script for deployment that downloads and installs an app.
The script I run:

```
curl url_GitHub | bash -s url_download_app
```

The script on GitHub:

```
#! /bin/sh
url="$2"
filename=$(basename "$url")
workpath=$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))
curl $url -o $workpath/$filename -s
sudo dpkg --install  $workpath/$filename
```

As I understood it doesn't pass the URL to download the app to the URL="$2" variable.

If I run the GitHub script locally, and pass the URL to download the app, it executes successfully.
Smth like:

```
bash install.sh -s url_download_app
```

Please help=)

Comment: I'm not really familiar with scripting. I've tried to find an answer by myself but failed. I had created an account here as my last chance=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-s` appears to be an option intended for the downloaded script. However, it is *also* an option accepted by `bash`, so what I think you want is

```
curl url_GitHub | bash -s -- -s url_download_app
```

Comment: unfortunately, failed: `bash: -s: no such file or directory`, `(23) Failed writing  body`

Comment: Oops, forgot to keep it as the `bash` option as well. The first `-s` tells `bash` to treat the remaining positional arguments as arguments to the script, not as positional arguments to `bash` itself. The `--` ensures that the next `-s` *is* treated as a positional argument.

Answer (score 1):

As the script on GitHub use $2, we should pass it as second argument :

```
curl url_GitHub | bash -s _ url_download_app
```

`_ url_download_app` will be passed to the script on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for the proposal, I have tried different numbers from $1 to $4. As I mention, it works as expected if it runs on a local machine `bash install.sh -s url_download_app`. If I use $1 it passes "-s"

Answer (score 0):

What about the following (using [process substitution](https://superuser.com/a/1060002/438726)):

```
bash <(curl -Ss url_GitHub) url_download_app
```

I did a proof of concept with the following script:

```
$ cat /tmp/test.sh 
#!/bin/bash
echo "I got '$1'"
exit 0
```

and when you run it you get:

```
$ bash <(cat /tmp/test.sh) "test input argument"
I got 'test input argument'
```

Comment: thank you.
for `bash <(curl -Ss url_GitHub) url_download_app` I changed the number of argument from $2 to $1 and **it passes the correct parameter**, but the workpath became `/proc/3748/fd` and `curl: is unknown -s` . So I modified the script on GitHub (remove -s parameter for curl `curl $url -o $workpath/$filename -s`) and failed with: `Warning: failed to create a file`, `Warning: /proc/3799/fd/"file.name"`, `Warning: No such file or directory`. @chepner 's approach helps. Thank you for your help. I learn new things =)

Comment: Number of params seems to work for me with `bash <(cat /tmp/test.sh) "test input argument" "123" "?"`. Regarding $workpath, it is expected to change with process substitution since `$0` is now a temp fd or pipe. You can use `workpath=$(pwd)` to get the current directory the user is in or pass the download/destination path as cmd argument